# replace NaN in matrix with other values

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix called `rf_rate`. Some of the rows are `NaN`. I wish to replace these NaN's with a certain row of the `rf_rate matrix`. So far I have the code below which is not giving me the correct answer.

```
miss_rf = isnan(rf_rate);    % getting a logical matrix of where NaN's are

% this us_rf is a row from the rf_rate matrix (us_pos is a single number)
us_rf = repmat(rf_rate(us_pos, :), length(rf_rate(:, 1)), 1);

% this is where its going wrong
rf_rate(miss_rf==1, :)          = us_rf(miss_rf(miss_rf==1), :);
```

My matrix is of size 56x11 but after the last line it goes to 611x11, why?

In my matrix `rf_rate` there are two rows which are `NaN` it is these two rows I want to replace.

Comment: Well, I doubt it to be any magic behind it. This is a typical situation where the debugger comes in handy http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html . You will also be able to look at the variables in the workspace and by howering over the variable and you can perform operations in the command window. We cannot say very much without knowing the size of your variables, but in case `miss_rf` is a matrix it will transform into a `Nx1` vector in the last row.

Comment: That looks to be exactly what is happening, do you have a reference to why/when this happens? I got a bit confused because just pasting in `rf_rate(miss_rf==1,:)` to see the shape gives me `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` error, but with the right-hand side as well it gives the error OP asks about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have only entire rows with `NaN` values and 'clean' rows everywhere else :**

```
% Number of rows to replace :
Nrows=sum(all(isnan(rf_rate),2));

% Replace the rows if Nrows>0:

if Nrows>0  

    rf_rate(all(isnan(rf_rate),2),:)=repmat(rf_rate(us_pos,:),Nrows,1);

end
```

**If you have a row of reference and you want, everytime a NaN appears in any other row, to replace it with the corresponding value in your row of reference :**

```
% Create a column vector of length `numel(rf_rate)` by repeating the first row :
Corrector=reshape(repmat(rf_rate(us_pos,:),size(rf_rate,1),1),[],1);

% Use linear indexing to fetch the NaN locations and replace them :
rf_rate(isnan(rf_rate(:)))=Corrector(isnan(rf_rate(:)));
```

---

### Example 1 :

```
rf_rate=magic(10);
rf_rate([2 3 7],:)=NaN;
us_pos=1;

rf_rate =

    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
    86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
    17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
    10    12    94    96    78    35    37    44    46    53
    11    18   100    77    84    36    43    50    27    59

% Apply code 1 :

% Number of rows to replace :
Nrows=sum(all(isnan(rf_rate),2));

% Replace the rows if Nrows>0:

if Nrows>0  

    rf_rate(all(isnan(rf_rate),2),:)=repmat(rf_rate(us_pos,:),Nrows,1);

end
```

**Output**

```
rf_rate =

    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
    85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
    86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
    17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
    79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
    10    12    94    96    78    35    37    44    46    53
    11    18   100    77    84    36    43    50    27    59
```

---

### Example 2 :

```
rf_rate=magic(10);
us_pos=1;
NanPos=randi(numel(rf_rate),10,1);
NanPos(mod(NanPos,10)==1)=[];
rf_rate(NanPos)=NaN;

rf_rate =

 92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
 98    80     7    14    16    73    55    57    64    41
  4   NaN    88    20    22    54    56   NaN    70   NaN
 85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
 86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
 17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
 23     5    82    89    91    48    30    32    39    66
 79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
NaN    12    94   NaN   NaN    35    37    44   NaN    53
 11    18   NaN    77    84    36   NaN    50    27    59

% Apply code 2 :

% Create a column vector of length `numel(rf_rate)` by repeating the first row :
Corrector=reshape(repmat(rf_rate(us_pos,:),size(rf_rate,1),1),[],1);

% Use linear indexing to fetch the NaN locations and replace them :
rf_rate(isnan(rf_rate(:)))=Corrector(isnan(rf_rate(:)));
```

**Output :**

```
rf_rate =

    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
    98    80     7    14    16    73    55    57    64    41
     4    99    88    20    22    54    56    51    70    40
    85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
    86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
    17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
    23     5    82    89    91    48    30    32    39    66
    79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
    92    12    94     8    15    35    37    44    58    53
    11    18     1    77    84    36    74    50    27    59
```

Note that the second version of the code works for bot cases.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out exactly what's happening with your code, but from your description I think what you want is

```
rf_rate(isnan(rf_rate)) = rf_rate(us_pos,:);
```

Note that unlike what you write, `us_rf` is not a row, but rather a matrix of the row repeated. Your code is taking that and inserting this several times.

Also note, this isn't particularly robust, and will fail if you have individual `NaN`s that don't take up an entire row.